# Angular Formly - RichEditor

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I need to create a form section template, so users can add/remove a new html form section on the fly.

I'm using [Angular-Formly](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly) for the form template. It works really well for me. However, I need to include a rich editor inside of my form

Can anyone here please provide direction for how to do that?  Can I write a angular directive to wrap a .Net rich editor in there? Has Angular-Formly provide a richEditor type or template already?

Comment: http://textangular.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

angular-formly doesn't provide a rich editor type out of the box, and I'm not aware of any open source integrations with one. But the textangular.com example as pointed out by @azium looks reasonable. It would be very simple to create a custom type using that directive. You could accomplish it like this (during the run phase):

```
formlyConfig.setType({
  name: 'richEditor',
  template: '<text-angular ng-model="model[options.key]"></text-angular>'
});
```

Here are [the docs](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v6.3.2/docs/custom-templates) on custom templates, here's [an example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/custom-types/custom-templates), and here's [a lesson on egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-formly-custom-templates?pl=7).